# Is lxml on selenium driver.page_source faster than multiple driver.find_element_by calls?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, lxml, screen-scraping

I am working on a screen scraping project and want to increase scraping speed. Using selenium is a project requirement.

Currently, our tool uses a selenium-only approach with successive `find_element_by_xpath` calls with the following logic (high-level):

**Current approach:**

```
def scrape_selenium():
    driver = create_driver()                     # Create driver instance
    driver.get(URL)                              # Get URL
    data1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(XPATH1) # Get data1
    if data1 is not None:                        # If data1 exists
       return data1                              # Return data1
    data2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(XPATH2) # Else, get other data
    if data2 is not None:                        # If data2 exists
       return data2                              # Return data2
    ...                                          # And so forth
    if data10 == None:                           # If data10 does not exists
       logger.warn("Nothing here, move on")      # Proceed to next URL
       return None                               
    else: 
       return data3                              # Else, return data10
```

In summary, there can be up to 10 consecutive calls following `driver.get(URL)`. Currently, we reach a scraping speed of ~500 URLs/min. This is rather slow, considering that we are using 50 async driver threads.

AFAIK, the `driver.get()` method returns when the page's load event fires. Therefore, all the HTML and CSS should be included at `driver.page_source` following `driver.get(URL)`.

*Hence I wonder if and when it makes sense to use `lxml` for parsing `driver.page_source` in terms of increasing scraping speed:*

**Alternative approach:**

```
def scrape_selenium_LXML():
    driver = create_driver()                     # Create driver instance
    driver.get(URL)                              # Get URL
    source = driver.get_page_source              # Get HTML/CSS
    html = lxml.html.parse(source)               # Parse using LXML
    for xpath_selector in XPATH_list:            # Loop through selector list
        data = html.xpath(xpath_selector)        # If data are found for selector
        if data is not None:
           return data                           # Return data
        else: 
            continue                             # Otherwise, use next selector
```

**Is a** `selenium + lxml` **approach possible as described above?**

**If so, when does it make sense to use approach 1 compared to approach 2?**

**Is a** `selenium + lxml` **approach faster than successive** `driver.find_elements_by_something()` **calls?**

---

**Edit**: I `%timeit` both scenarios in the moment, but would be grateful for the experience of others or some hints towards "good practice" in general

Comment: Did you time both the methods using `timeit`? I guess you could answer your own question using that.

Comment: I am doing exactly that in the moment - My intention asking this is to learn about the experience others have made, maybe there are some "good practices" that I am not aware of

Comment: If you have the `timeit` results, add them in the question. Maybe it'll help others to give better answers.